# Inject javascript array values into multiple HTML locations using a loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I want to be able to populate an array with numbers and inject the value from that array into my HTML code in 2 places at a time. In this code I'd like the value in array position 1 `[0]` to hold the value 53498 and insert itself into the position below in `value` and in `<div class="n1">53498</div>`.
I'd like the value in array position 2 `[1]` to hold the value 12500 and insert itself into the positions below in `value` and in `<div class="n2">1250</div>`...and so on for all the 10+ HTML rows that will be there.
The naming conventions on the targeted classes will be n1, n2, n3 so the iteration on a loop can be 1,2,3... I basically want to be able to populate these values in 1 place instead of scrolling through the HTML to find the values each time I want to update the value.
Even being able to add some code to each position that extracts the array value would work for me e.g. `value="53498"` => `value="*array output[0]*"` and `<div class="n1">53498</div>` => `<div class="n1">*array output[0]*</div>`

Thanks

```
#row1
<div class="grid__item grid__item--3"><input type="checkbox" id="n1" value="53498" data-rel="div.n1" autocomplete="off"> Show Price</div>
<div class="grid__item grid__item--3"><div class="n1">53498</div></div>
#row2
<div class="grid__item grid__item--3"><input type="checkbox" id="n2" value="12500" data-rel="div.n1" autocomplete="off"> Show Price</div>
<div class="grid__item grid__item--3"><div class="n2">12500</div></div>
...
...
#row10 etc...
```

I thought a derivation of the below may do the trick?

```
<div id="n1"></div>
<div id="n2"></div>
```

and

```
<script>
const nums = ["53498", "12500"];
let item = "";
for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("n"+[i]).innerHTML = item;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This concept seems to work for me:

```
  <input type="checkbox" id="cn0" value="" data-rel="div.n1" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cn1" value="" data-rel="div.n1" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cn2" value="" data-rel="div.n1" autocomplete="off">
    <div id="n0"></div>
    <div id="n1"></div>
    <div id="n2"></div>
```

and js

```
    <script>
    const nums = [53498,12500];
    let item = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
      item = nums[i];
      citem = nums[i];
      document.getElementById("n"+ i).innerText = item;
      document.getElementById("cn"+ i).value = citem;
      alert("item="+item);
      alert("citem="+item);
    }
    </script>
```